# Django: Find all values in a ManyToMany relationship where all elements of the related set match certain criteria

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-orm

I have two models in a ManyToMany relationship.  I want to get a subset of the first model for which *every* related model matches certain criteria.

Scenario: This is for a collaborative dictionary.  A Word may have 0 or more Definitions. A Definition may be in a number of states: "complete", "in progress" or "abandoned".  I am interested in finding all Words which have either no Definitions or *only* have "abandoned" Definitions.

```
class DefinitionState(Enum):
    COMPLETE = 0
    IN_PROGRESS = 1
    ABANDONED = 2

class Definition(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    status = models.IntegerField()

class Word(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(length=60)
    definitions = models.ManyToManyField(Definition, related="words")

spam = Word.objects.create(text="spam")
eggs = Word.objects.create(text="eggs")
bacon = Word.objects.create(text="bacon")
lobster = Word.objects.create(text="lobster")

spam_d1 = Definition.objects.create(
    text="Processed meat", 
    status=DefinitionState.COMPLETE
)
spam_d2 = Definition.objects.create(
    text="Unwanted email",
    status=DefinitionState.ABANDONED
)
spam.definitions.add(spam_d1)
spam.definitions.add(spam_d2)

eggs_d = Definition.objects.create(
    text="Laid by chickens",
    status=DefinitionState.COMPLETE
)
eggs.definitions.add(eggs_d)

bacon_d = Definition.objects.create(
    text="Part of a pig",
    status=DefinitionState.ABANDONED
)
bacon.definitions.add(bacon_d)
```

So I have four Words:

- `spam`, which has one COMPLETE definition and one ABANDONED definition;
- `eggs`, which has one COMPLETE definition;
- `bacon`, which has one ABANDONED definition;
- `lobster`, which has no definitions.

I want to write a query which will return `(bacon, lobster)` (in no particular order).

I can write the query to return `lobster`:

```
Word.objects.annotate(Count("definitions")).filter(definitions__count=0)
```

and I can identify which definitions are abandoned:

```
Definition.objects.filter(status=DefinitionState.ABANDONED)
```

but I can't figure out how to ask for Words whose Definitions are all ABANDONED.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Words.objects.exclude(definitions__status__in=[COMPLETE, IN_PROGRESS])
```

Comment: This would include `Word` objects that have no definitions at all, otherwise fine.

Comment: Expected behavior. See 'lobster' example above

Comment: You are right @Nidal. I'd already voted up your answer else I'd do it again :-)

Comment: Sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees.  Thanks @Nidal :)

Comment: It turned out that this solution became **really** slow (over 20 minutes) once I applied it to the real database, where I have over 108,000 Definitions and over 119,000 Words.  1627 Words needed to be returned from the query. I wound up putting an "abandoned" BooleanField on Word, which will be updated periodically and/or via a post_save signal on Definition.